# ng:areq Argument is not a function, got undefined in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, sorting

I am trying to make div sortable(drag and drop) using angularjs. i have made one demo which working fine. but when i implemented in project it gives an error.

look out the below code.

```
<div ng-app="reportingModule">
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="sortableController" ng-init="chartCollection = @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartViewModelCollection)">
    <ul id="dashboard" ui-sortable ng-model="chartCollection">
        <li ng-repeat="chart in chartCollection" ng-style="setColour(chartCollection.length)">
            <div>
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i have two JS file for maintain code standard.

SortingJS.js

```
angular.module('reportingModule', ['ui.sortable'])
.controller("sortableController", function ($scope) {
    var tmpList = [];
    $scope.sortingLog = [];

    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            // this callback has the changed model
            var logEntry = tmpList.map(function (i) {
                return i.value;
            }).join(', ');
            $scope.sortingLog.push('Stop: ' + logEntry);
        }
    };
})
```

ReportingMenu.js :

```
angular.module('reportingModule')
    .controller('reportingMenuController', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "chartDetailsService", "reportingFocus", function ($scope, $rootScope, chartDetailsService, reportingFocus) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
 ])
```

I got `[ng:areq] Argument 'reportingMenuController' is not a function, got undefined` error.

when i remove `['ui.sortable']` from sorting.js file error goes away..but sorting is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the "Creation versus Retrieval" section of the angular [module guide page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module),

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and **overwrite any existing module named myModule**. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

So, it looks like you either have another file out there creating your "reportingModule" module or the order of these files is incorrect. My mistake was the former.

Make sure the module is being *created* only once (only one file has angular.module('reportingModule', [...])) and make sure that file is the first module file that is referenced in your index.html.